# some Novice assembly need determine

Tags: assembly, 8051

I was just learning assembly Language. there is my question I don't understand

such as that
`MOV A, @R0`
I think the Source is Indirect
   the Destination is Accumulator

am I correct?

Comment: There's no such instruction as `MOV` on Z80 CPU. Also the "assembly language" is a bit exaggeration, it's more like "languages", each CPU has it's own, often with several dialects and specific target modes, so even on single CPU it can often feel like three different ones, just sharing basic instruction names...

Comment: _"I was just learning assembly Language"_ You need to specify the architecture you're targetting, and which assembler you're using.

Comment: That looks like 8051, I have added the tag.